# Merge Candidates: [n-tier] and [n-tier-architecture]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[image]

[Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/n-tier/info) for [n-tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n-tier).
[Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/n-tier-architecture/info) for [n-tier-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture).

Comment: These seem similar enough, you've got my vote. My preference would be to see [tag:n-tier-architecture] stick around since it's more explicit. Since there's only 500, I don't mind helping with manual re-tagging.

Comment: I assume you're wanting to re-tag and add a synonym for one of these. Can you add that to your request? I don't want to act on it before we get consensus :)

Comment: @CarrieKendall I'm not really concerned with which way these go and I'm not particularly knowledgeable of the most common phrasing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I propose we make [n-tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n-tier) a synonym that points to [n-tier-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture).

Comment: Re-tagging like that, especially if we also make the synonym, is pure absolutely pointless busy-work. There are enough other requests which actually might need a human touch.

Comment: What Deduplicator is pointing out that if you make it a synonym it will retag them all for you.  So just go to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/n-tier/synonyms and vote for that if you have the points.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I didn't know that, thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf That synonym is pointing the wrong way!  We need to vote it down so the right synonym can be created.

Comment: "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms"    As I don't have points for that tag it would be a matter of drawing the attention to this thread to the users that do.