# Merge/Synonymize Proposal: [uiautomator] [android-uiautomator]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just became aware of this, but would need to wait some time for my lazy reputation.

[uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiautomator)'s wiki:

> The uiautomator testing framework lets you test your user interface (UI) efficiently by creating automated functional UI testcases

[android-uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-uiautomator)'s wiki

> The uiautomator testing framework lets you test your user interface (UI) efficiently by creating automated functional UI testcases

<strike>I am also curious by which criteria would the **Master** and **Synonym** positions be selected.</strike>

Does an overall higher number of questions of a tag make it the Master? Or is it the latest frequency of the used tag? Does it even matter which is which?

**EDIT**
While tagging this tag-related question, I realized that my assumption might be wrong in the first place. If the two tags refer to the same thing, isn't this then a **duplicate** / **merge** situation?

Comment: If they mean the same thing and are used in the same way, one should become a synonym of the other.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but then I saw this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291820/merge-candidates-n-tier-and-n-tier-architecture

Comment: Did you read the answer and the comments on the answer there?

Comment: Yes, and the terminology added to the confusion.
Why would declaring them synonyms be "pure absolutely pointless busy-work" if they are retagged automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the [39 questions that were not tagged with any android related characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buiautomator%5D+-%5Bandroid-uiautomator%5D+-%5Badb%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bappium%5D+is%3Aq+-%22android%22+&mixed=0), turns out they were all related to Android's UI Automator [except one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036352/how-to-inspect-the-element-of-flash-using-c), which was closed as too broad (which I deleted).

Given that both the tags are related to Android's uiautomator, it made sense to merge them. I've added [uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiautomator) as a synonym for [android-uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-uiautomator), that is [uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiautomator) (× 586) → [android-uiautomator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-uiautomator) (× 311). I'll merge the two tags in a few days, if there are no issues.